# Spring MVC Rest service consume JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I am trying to create and **Rest API** with **Spring MVC** that consumes **JSON**:

**Controller:**

```
@RestController public class CrawlerController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/checkForMarfeelizableSite", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseR checkForMarfeelizableSites(@RequestBody List<Entry> list) {

    // Response
    ResponseR responseR = new ResponseR();
    responseR.setOperationResult(OperationResult.OK);

    for (Entry entry : list) {
        System.out.println("Entry: " + entry);
    }

    return responseR;
} }
```

**Entry.class**

```
public class Entry {

String url;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app>

<display-name>Marfeel Marfeelizable Checker</display-name>

<!-- Spring Context -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/marfeel-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>marfeel-crawler-api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>marfeel-crawler-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Welcome file List -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I've added the **Jackson lib** (jackson-mapper-asl) in my pom.xml, but I'm receiving a `HTTP 415 Error`

This is a sample of json that I'm sending:

```
[{"url": "c­and­a.com"},{"url": "toshiba.es"}]
```

Comment: Are you setting the Content-type header correctly in the request?

Comment: I am testing it with postman! I am sending the raw json but I am not adding anything else! Which header should I add?

Comment: Content-type: application/json

Comment: Thank you @DavidFrank!! I have my service running now... the trouble was that I was not sending the header on the request. The service was totally correct!

Answer (score 0):

could you check the followings?

- Change

> public ResponseR checkForMarfeelizableSites(@RequestBody *List*
>   list)

**to**

> public ResponseR checkForMarfeelizableSites(@RequestBody
>   **ArrayList** list)

(since List is an interface and therefore cannot create an instance).

- Entry.class: add @XmlRootElement above the class name,and an empty contractor (required for web exportable classes)